# "О чувствах вроде(:) боли, гнева или радости". Нужно ли двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Нужно ли двоеточие после "вроде" в предложении: "*Совсем скоро люди позабудут о чувствах вроде(:) боли, гнева или радости*"?

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие не ставится: Совсем скоро люди позабудут о чувствах (каких? ) **вроде боли, гнева или радости.**

Здесь нет обобщающего слова, как, например, в таком предложении: **Совсем скоро люди забудут эти чувства:  боль, гнев или радость.**

***Вроде*** ― это предлог со значением "наподобие", сочетание ***вроде боли, гнева или радости*** ― несогласованное определение, которое в нормальной позиции после слова с неопределенным значением (***о чувствах***) не обособляется, так как является **его основным определением**.

Обособление возможно **при пояснительном  значении оборота**, когда у существительного уже есть другое определение, например:

Мадам Петракова, изнывая от любопытства, и своё ухо подставила к пухлым масленым губам Бобы, а тот, изредка воровски оглядываясь, всё шептал и шептал, и можно было расслышать **отдельные слова, вроде таких**: [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 2 (1929-1940)]

Comment: В данном контексте слово "вроде" портит стилистику, его следует заменить или вообще убрать. Вы правы.

Comment: О стиле можно говорить, но желательно и ответ дать на вопрос: ставится ли двоеточие (или другой знак) в такой грамматической конструкции и почему?

Comment: Двоеточие перед перечислением означает, что перечисление точное и исчерпывающее. Оно мобилизует внимание читающего.  Этому помогают дополнительные вводные конструкции : а именно, как то, такие как, итд.  "Вроде" наоборот означает приблизительность, неточность. Поэтому двоеточие лишнее. И разговорное "вроде" лучше убрать вместе с ним или заменить на "например".  Затрудняюсь определить роль двоеточия в приведённой Вами цитате. Выглядит как перечисление, но скорее отделяет прямую речь без кавычек: Такой-то сказал ДВОЕТОЧИЕ .....

Comment: То, что вы говорите, к правилам не имеет отношения. 1) Двоеточие предупреждает о последующем пояснении, раскрытии темы  и соответствует увеличенной паузе с неполным понижением тона. Этот знак характерен для бессоюзных предложений и предложений с обобщающим словом. 2) У предлога ВРОДЕ нет стилистической пометки (разг.), он используется в текстах разного стиля. В то же время частичный конфликт возможен, если тематика текста связана с рассуждениями на высокие темы. Редактирование очень простое: Совсем скоро люди позабудут о таких чувствах, как  боль, гнев или радость.

Comment: 3) В моем предложении всё очень просто: двоеточие ставится после обобщающего слова перед однородным рядом. Предложение приведено с определенной целью, а именно показать, что в заданном варианте обобщающего слова нет и двоеточия ставить не нужно.